# Loud Fan and "Overclocking Failed"

Tags: fan, noise

Recently, my computer has begun making louder fan noises than usual. I opened my computer to see if there was anything obvious affecting the fan (e.g., dust), but I didn't see anything. I did some research and downloaded a program called SpeedFan, but to be honest, I have no clue how to interpret these readings:

[image: readings]

I've also been having another potentially related problem. Occasionally, when I try to wake my computer from sleep, there is no response (and the reset button doesn't work), and I need to disconnect power. Upon restarting, it says, "Overclocking failed." To the extent of my knowledge, I haven't ever overclocked my computer. (The computer works fine after that error message is shown.)

Can anyone shed some light on what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readings look good, so it's probably not too high temperature.

I has similar problem with Asus P6T Deluxe V2 motherboard. The overclocking failed message may be just badly designed BIOS. Apparently some people can't imagine another reason to turn power off other than failed overclock. It probably resets settings back to default too. Check the fan speed settings in BIOS. They were probably set back to default, which is probably full speed. If that's the case, you may need to change them.

As for computer not waking up, I'd say that the problem is probably ACPI related. Try uninstalling motherboard drivers and getting newest ones from motherboard manufacturer. It may help. Also, which motherboard do you have?

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks! Changing the fan speed settings did the trick. On the second issue, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'll see whether the issue comes up again. (I have the ASUS P5QL-CM.)